# Laravel 6.6, load balancer and redis managed cluster on DO... problem with CSRF Token while login

Tags: laravel, redis, load-balancing, csrf

I am testing an infrastructure for a web application which include a load balancer, a database server and 2 web servers. All the server are on the same datacenter (provided by Digital Ocean)
The redis server is a manager database product from DO too.

I'm using laravel 6.6.

The load balancer works well (using the Round Robin algorithm), but when I try to login, I always got 419 page exception.

Here is the detail of my env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

I am using redis to share the session, but it's not working.

Someone has an idea to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out Vapor for serverless laravel deployment? (I know, not a direct answer to your question but worth checking out if you keep running into problems setting this up)

Comment: Yes I tried but I don't feel confortable to use it on production yet

Comment: Facing the same problem with Laravel 8. Session holds between the 4 servers connected to same Redis instance, but CSRF token value keeps regenerating on every request.